# Getting Word Recognition in Windows Phone Speech

Tags: speech, speech-to-text

I am working with the Windows Phone Speech Recognition and I would like to be able to take the following speech:

I walked one hundred miles

and be able to be able to know, in my app, that hundred means 100

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedphrase.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) RecognizedPhrase.Text Property should contain the display text format which is what you are asking for.

> As part of the speech recognition process, the speech recognizer performs speech-to-text normalization of the recognized input into a display form.
>
> For example, the spoken input, "twenty five dollars", generates a recognition result where the Words property contains the words, "twenty", "five", and "dollars", and the Text property contains the phrase, **"$25.00"**. For more information about text normalization, see ReplacementText.